# Accessing the web service in an ios application

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to send the XML data to a web service. But i am not getting any responce from the service. when i tried to send  the XML through SOAPUI... i got the error as "Incoming parameter failiure"..can any one please check my code and point me on what i am doing wrong..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    NSString *Message = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
                     "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope \n"
                         "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" \n"
                     "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" \n" 
                     "xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \n"
                     "SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \n"
                     "xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> \n"
                     "<SOAP-ENV:Body> \n"
                     "<XMLGetReportParameters xmlns=\"http://PlusDiagnostics.Schemas.GetReportParameters\"><UserName xmlns="">USERNAME</UserName><Password xmlns="">PASSWORD</Password><List xmlns="">All</List></XMLGetReportParameters>" 
                     "</SOAP-ENV:Body> \n"
                     "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>" ];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://pathflexstage.plusdx.com/MobileReporting/GetPathologyReports.svc"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [Message length]];
    NSLog(@"message length is %d",[Message length]);

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/IGetPathologyReports/GetReports" forHTTPHeaderField:@"soapAction"];

    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [Message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // NSLog("return");
    NSLog(@"%@",returnString);

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: You might want to remove your password from the code. Have you tried sending your XML to the server in a desktop browser? Like Firefox with the extension Poster?

Comment: I do not agree with this being closed, it would have really helped me when I was learning how to access web services via iphone/objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be receiving something back from the server, possibly an error.

Declare the following;

```
NSURLResponse *response = nil; 
NSError *error = nil;
```

...and then make your request like so;

```
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

...if you then inspect response and error, you should be able to find the route of you problem.